# dataReceived() method confusing behaviour in python twisted framework

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to learn the python twisted internet framework but one thing has confused me. Initial testing with telnet shows that the `protocol.Protocol.dataReceived()` method is called whenever it receives data. So if i define it as follows, it waits for an EOL before firing:

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    print "MyProtocol::dataReceived, (%s)" %(data)
```

output:

```
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (dgdfg
)
```

however, as soon as i add an extra line:

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    print "MyProtocol::dataReceived, (%s)" %(data)
    self.transport.write(data)
```

it fires for every character.

output:

```
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (d)
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (g)
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (d)
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (f)
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (g)
MyProtocol::dataReceived, (
)
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

The Factory is `protocol.Factory` and the protocol is `protocol.Protocol`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Line buffering does not take place before `dataReceived` fires ([docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IProtocol.html#dataReceived)), so there are no guarantees that what you receive is EOL-delimited. This is unlikely to be the root of your problem though, since the messages you send fit in the default read chunk size. Could you perhaps share the rest of your code?

There is a `LineReceiver` protocol that you could look into ([docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html#setLineMode)) that takes care of the line-buffering for you. Here's an example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.protocols import basic

class EchoLine(basic.LineReceiver):
    delimiter = '\n'  # default is '\r\n'

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print("received: %s" % line)
        self.sendLine(line)

class EchoFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = EchoLine

reactor.listenTCP(port, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The client you're using is sometimes doing line buffering before sending.  Perhaps you switched between two clients to get the difference in buffering behavior, or perhaps you toggled a buffering option in the client.